# Setting proxy exceptions to TFS SDK

Tags: java, tfs, proxy, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS java SDK in my application which is connecting TFS server running in private network. My application connects to outside internet as well. For that connection we need to set proxy in my application. when i set those proxy then I am no more able to connect to our TFS server via our application.

This is how I am configuring proxy settings in for TFS SDK.

```
public class TFSHTTPClientFactory extends DefaultHTTPClientFactory {

public TFSHTTPClientFactory(final ConnectionInstanceData instanceData){
 super(instanceData);
}

@Override
public void configureClientProxy(
  final HttpClient httpClient,
  final HostConfiguration hostConfiguration,
  final HttpState httpState,
  final ConnectionInstanceData instanceData) {

  System.setProperty("com.microsoft.tfs.client.allowInsecureBasic", "true"); 

  String proxyHost = null;
  int proxyPort;

   if(ProxyConfigurator.httpProxyHost!=null) {
    proxyHost = ProxyConfigurator.httpProxyHost;
       proxyPort = ProxyConfigurator.httpProxyPort;
   } else {
     proxyHost = ProxyConfigurator.httpsProxyHost;
     proxyPort = ProxyConfigurator.httpsProxyPort;
   }

   hostConfiguration.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);

  }
}
```

To overcome this i was planning to add proxy exceptions to my proxy configuration but i couldn't find any way in TFS HostConfiguration class where i can put this. Can any one guide how to set proxy exceptions or is there any other way where I can skip the proxy settings when accessing TFS server ?

Comment: Try to reference the [`configureClientProxy`](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/master/source/com.microsoft.tfs.sdk.samples.console/src/com/microsoft/tfs/sdk/samples/console/ConnectionAdvisorSample.java) in team-explorer-everywhere (Java client for TFS), and this : https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/34 check if that helps.